# Boot the Raspberry Pi 2 with custom kernel and initramfs

Tags: boot, pi-2, kernel

I want to boot my Raspberry Pi 2 with a custom configuration. Therefore I have a kernel image and an initramfs file. The /boot directory looks like this:

```
/boot/my_kernel.img
/boot/my_initrd.img
```

I would like to use the minimum of files in /boot. I copy:

```
/boot/bootcode.bin
/boot/fixup.dat
/boot/start.elf
```

from https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware.
After that I create the file

```
/boot/cmdline.txt
```

with the arguments for the kernel. Finally I create

```
/boot/config.txt
```

with the following content:

```
kernel=my_kernel.img
initramfs my_initrd.img followkernel
```

My questions:

- Is this enough to boot the Raspberry Pi 2 or do I need something else?
- Can I remove fixup.dat?

Comment: Has this worked?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about `fixup.dat` but — *provided you derived your kernel configuration from the Pi2's* — replace the kernel and initrd and Bob's your uncle. FYI I did that with an Orange Pi, not exactly a Raspberry Pi but it's close. My kernel was compiled on a Gentoo environment and fetched from [Sunxi 3.4](http://linux-sunxi.org/Linux_Kernel). It did work.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, the second SD card has just arrived.